# Failed Convert Varchar to a Float

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, isnumeric

I have a table that has got a mixture of data, its of type Varchar but i has got numbers and a few strings in it which are `Building` and `IBS`. However i'm trying to get rid of the strings. I only know how to get rid of one. When i try to add another, It complains about arguments, how can i do it.

```
ROUND( ISNULL( CASE 
                  WHEN [lentgth] IN( 'Building', '', 'IBS', '') THEN 0 
                  ELSE CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([lentgth], 'm', 'i')) 
               END, 0 ), 0 )
```

Comment: You simply can NOT convert text to float when it contains non-numeric characters.

Comment: when the value should by float, does it have a dot or a comma as decimal seperator ? I believe it has to be a dot so have you checked that ?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data please ?

Comment: I have used the isnumeric function and its worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [isnumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function:

```
ROUND(cast(case
            when isnumeric(lentgth) = 0 then 0 
            else lentgth
           end as float)
     , 0)
```

Comment: This will work on almost any values, but beware that there does exist a couple of single character values that will make this fail, including . (dot) and , (comma). See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manub22/2013/12/23/use-new-try_parse-instead-of-isnumeric-sql-server-2012/

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([lentgth], 'm', 'i'))
```

This returns `NULL` if the conversion cannot be done.  If you want `0`, use `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()`:

```
ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, REPLACE([lentgth], 'm', 'i')), 0)
```

`COALECE()` evaluates the first argument twice (which I consider to be an MS SQL performance bug).  For that reason, `ISNULL()` is preferable when the first argument is a function all or subquery.